# Two ane file conflict in one flex mobile application

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air-native-extension

I have two ane file for video recorder. One is for android and another is for ios device. Both have different package name and methods.

Now, i import both `Native Extension` in single project. And detect ios and android device following way:

```
if(Capabilities.version.indexOf('IOS') > -1) //for ios device
```

And

```
if(Capabilities.version.indexOf('AND') > -1) //for android device
```

And create object for each class. Now when i run that it gives error for another ane class not found.

Like Suppose i check in ios then gives error for android ane file class, Event not found. same for android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an ANE that only supports Android it won't be available at all when run in Ios (same is true for Ios). If it has a default implementation its classes will be available but if it doesn't then its classes will just not exist in that scope and error will be thrown if you try to reference them. When using ANE that only offer one platform implementation those ANE have to be used only when compiling for that platform. The way you can switch between ANEs easily is by using CONFIG constants.

EDIT: Defining constants. Right Click project and choose "properties", in "Actionscript compiler" add as many config lines as you see fit, for example:

```
-define=CONFIG::ANDROID,false
-define=CONFIG::IOS,false
```

Now wrap all code (including import statements) referencing the Android ANE and the IOS ANE with:

```
CONFIG::ANDROID
{
    //android code here
}
CONFIG::IOS
{
    //ios code here
}
```

Now your 2 config variables are set to false so no code in between "CONFIG::ANDROID" or "CONFIG::IOS" will be compiled with your app. Now if in "actionscript compiler" you change:

```
-define=CONFIG::ANDROID,true
```

All code that is in between "CONFIG::ANDROID" will be compiled (you can use "CONFIG::ANDROID" anywhere in your code as many times as you want).

So before compiling set one config to true and make sure the other is set to false and the right code for the right platform will be compiled.

Comment: How can i use CONFIG constants?

Comment: Thanks. it's working good +1 for that. But if i want to use multiple times then it will become confusing or lots of separation. Is there any better solution for that?

Comment: I'm not understanding that.

Comment: There's no better solution to the given problem. As I said if those ANE had implemented a default (as3 implementation) this would not be a problem. You could yourself create those default classes in your project and remove the need for config constants. You basically create empty classes using exact same package path and classes names then create exact same methods and simply leave those methods empty. If done correctly that should provide the default implementation for those anes.

Comment: When defining more than one namespace and variable in the compiler arguments, you need to use *define+=* for the definitons after the first *define=*

Answer (score 0):

Capabilities.version will tell you: "Specifies the Flash Player or Adobe® AIR® platform and version information." and not the OS version you are running on.

See here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#version

You need to use Capabilities.os instead 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#os